# How can i inject Apache-CXF client proxy web service bean(s) registered in BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf, jax-ws, autowired

I am registering the bean definition in X project's BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor class. These beans are created by Apache-CXF(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean)'s **create** method.

```
BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                            .genericBeanDefinition(Class.forName(endpoint.getServiceName()));
builder.addConstructorArgValue(Class.forName(endpoint.getServiceName()));
builder.addConstructorArgValue(endpointUrl);
builder.setFactoryMethodOnBean("create", "jaxWsProxyCreator");

registry.registerBeanDefinition(endpoint.getServiceName(), builder.getBeanDefinition());
LOGGER.info("Registred endpoint url like : " + endpointUrl);
```

The JaxWsProxyCreator class:

```
public class JaxWsProxyCreator extends JaxWsProxyFactoryBean{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JaxWsProxyCreator.class);

    public JaxWsProxyCreator(){
        super();
    }

    public Object create(Class<?> clazz, String endpointUrl){
        Object proxy = null;
        try {
            super.setServiceClass(clazz);
            super.setAddress(endpointUrl);
            proxy = super.create();
            logger.info("Client proxy created : " + endpointUrl);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error creating service : " + ClassUtils.getQualifiedName(clazz), e);
        }
        return proxy;
    }

}
```

I can access my web service beans in application context as below and it is working clearly.

```
MyWebService bean = (MyWebService) applicationContext.getBean(MyWebService.class);
```

But when I want to autowire these web service beans in another Spring beans with @Autowired. it throws the exception like:

> Error creating bean with name 'BusinessLogicServiceBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myWebService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xx.xx.xx.MyWebService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

By the way: I can autowire normal non-cxf registered beans in the same **BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor** class.

Is there any trick/workaround for autowiring capability for dynamically registered apache cxf client proxy beans?

Thank you.

Comment: If you’ve been waiting longer than you’d like for an answer, I would recommend updating your question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: I come across the same problem here, have you resolved it and how?

Comment: unfortunately, no.